# Subscript out of range - runtime error 9

Tags: vba, excel

can you please advise why the below code does not select the visible sheets, but ends in a runtime error.  This is driving me crazy.  Thanks for any help.

```
Sub SelectSheets1()

    Dim mySheet As Object
    Dim mysheetarray As String

    For Each mySheet In Sheets
        With mySheet
            If .Visible = True And mysheetarray = "" Then
                mysheetarray = "Array(""" & mySheet.Name
            ElseIf .Visible = True Then
                mysheetarray = mysheetarray & """, """ & mySheet.Name
            Else
            End If
        End With
    Next mySheet        

    mysheetarray = mysheetarray & """)"                
    Sheets(mysheetarray).Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Please find the time to mark one of the answers you got below as "Answer", by clicking on the V next to it (and it will turn green)

Answer (score 3):

Long story short - you are giving a string (`mysheetarray`) when it is expecting array. VBA likes to get what it expects.

Long story long - this is the way to select all visible sheets:

```
Option Explicit

Sub SelectAllVisibleSheets()

    Dim varArray()          As Variant
    Dim lngCounter          As Long

    For lngCounter = 1 To Sheets.Count
        If Sheets(lngCounter).Visible Then
            ReDim Preserve varArray(lngCounter - 1)
            varArray(lngCounter - 1) = lngCounter
        End If
    Next lngCounter

    Sheets(varArray).Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You should define `Dim mySheet As Object` as `Worksheet`.

Also, you can use an array of `Sheet.Name`s that are visible.

**Code**

```
Sub SelectSheets1()

    Dim mySheet As Worksheet
    Dim mysheetarray() As String
    Dim i As Long

    ReDim mysheetarray(Sheets.Count) '< init array to all existing worksheets, will optimize later
    i = 0
    For Each mySheet In Sheets
        If mySheet.Visible = xlSheetVisible Then
            mysheetarray(i) = mySheet.Name
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next mySheet

    ReDim Preserve mysheetarray(0 To i - 1) '<-- optimize array size    
    Sheets(mysheetarray).Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Be careful, this won't work when in the Workbook will be more then 100 visible sheets. In that case here `mysheetarray(i) = mySheet.Name` the error 9 will occur: index out of range.

Comment: @dee I know, it happens to you very often that you use a workbook with 500 sheets ? but just in case, is 1000 enough ?

Comment: Yes 1000 sounds better, but maybe when using this solution then `ReDim mysheetarray(Sheets.Count)` would assume all the sheets are visible first.

Comment: @dee nice idea, on it :)

Comment: I don't want to be picky but with `Option Base 1` the error 9 occures as well.

Comment: No I don't see it in your code. But maybe the @RichardScott can use it or someone who will see this answer later. But forget it, I didn't want to be picky so ... :)

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to explain the `Sheets` a little, HTH.
Note: `Sheets` property is defined on `Workbook` and on `Application` objects, both works and returns the `Sheets-Collection`.

```
Option Explicit

Sub SheetsDemo()
    ' All sheets
    Dim allSheets As Sheets
    Set allSheets = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets

    ' Filtered sheets by sheet name
    Dim firstTwoSheets As Sheets
    Set firstTwoSheets = allSheets.Item(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2"))
    ' or simply: allSheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2"))
    ' Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2") is function which returns Variant with strings

    ' So you simply need an array of sheet names which are visible
    Dim visibleSheetNames As String
    Dim sh As Variant ' Sheet class doesn't exist so we can use Object or Variant
    For Each sh In allSheets
        If sh.Visible Then _
            visibleSheetNames = visibleSheetNames & sh.Name & ","
    Next sh

    If Strings.Len(visibleSheetNames) > 0 Then
        ' We have some visible sheets so filter them out
        visibleSheetNames = Strings.Left(visibleSheetNames, Strings.Len(visibleSheetNames) - 1)
        Dim visibleSheets As Sheets
        Set visibleSheets = allSheets.Item(Strings.Split(visibleSheetNames, ","))

        visibleSheets.Select

    End If
End Sub
```